# How to access host's local network from Rancher Desktop?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

I am very new to Rancher.
I am using Rancher Desktop on Windows, and I want to communicate wit a device that is attached to the host's local network.

The container runtime is 'containered'

Is there a command line argument while running the image that can help me do this ?

I tried `--network="host"` option but that does not work.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Where exactly is the problem? Did you see [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#containerd)?

Comment: I am using the image for my development, with all the tools and compiler installed on it. I have the target device connected to the host via JLink and I want to write the image to it. For this there is a JLink Remote Server, where the communication can be done with an ip.
I had a docker setup earlier, and on that while running the image if I used --network="host" as command line argument, then it worked fine.